# Python Pandas KeyError: 'the label is not in the [index]'

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a `duplicates_to_fetch` data frame of index :

```
            mail_domaine         Values
0                 @A.com         [0, 2]
1                 @B.com         [1, 4]
```

And the following `df_to_rearrange` data frame

```
        movie_name              df_pname 
0                A                [mr a]   
1                B                [mr b]   
2               Aa               [mr aa]   
3                D                [mr d]   
4               Bb       [mr Bb, mr Bbb]
5                E                [mr e]
```

I would like to have the following transformed data frame

```
        movie_name                    df_pname 
0          [A, Aa]               [mr a, mr aa]   
1          [B, Bb]       [mr b, mr Bb, mr Bbb]   
3              [D]                      [mr d] 
5              [E]                      [mr e]
```

However... when I drop the lines, the algorithm stops because of missing index

I did like

```
for i in range(0,len(druplicates_to_fetch)):
      mylist = duplicates_to_fetch.loc[i,"Values"]
      index_to_fetch_on = mylist[0]

      # rearrange mylist (which can have >2 values)
      mylist = [myindex for myindex in mylist if myindex != index_to_fetch_on]

      for j in mylist:
            df_to_rearrange.loc[index_to_fetch, "df_pname"].append(df_to_rearrange.loc[j, "df_pname"])
            df_to_rearrange.drop(df_to_rearrange.index[j], inplace=True)
```

The error is the following `KeyError: 'the label [179] is not in the [index]'`. Id there a more Pythonic way to do this ?

Comment: Iterating with `for i in range(0,len(duplicates_to_fetch)): mylist = duplicates_to_fetch.loc[i,"Values"]` is clunky. Better to do: `for i, duplicate_row in duplicates_to_fetch.iterrows()`

Comment: Also, `mylist = [ix for ix in mylist if ix != index_to_fetch_on]` looks like a simple `drop()` operation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another to way to do it. Use `lookup` for groups, and `agg` the columns to `list`

```
In [78]: lookup = {v: i for i, x in enumerate(duplicates_to_fetch['Values']) for v in x}

In [79]: (df_to_rearrange.groupby(df_to_rearrange.index.to_series().map(lookup).fillna(''))
             .agg({'movie_name': lambda x: [v for v in x], 
                   'df_pname': lambda x: [a for v in x.values for a in v]})
             .reset_index(drop=True))
Out[79]:
  movie_name               df_pname
0    [A, Aa]          [mr a, mr aa]
1    [B, Bb]  [mr b, mr Bb, mr Bbb]
2        [D]                 [mr d]
```

---

Details

```
In [959]: duplicates_to_fetch
Out[959]:
  mail_domaine  Values
0       @A.com  [0, 2]
1       @B.com  [1, 4]

In [960]: df_to_rearrange
Out[960]:
  movie_name         df_pname
0          A           [mr a]
1          B           [mr b]
2         Aa          [mr aa]
3          D           [mr d]
4         Bb  [mr Bb, mr Bbb]
In [958]: lookup
Out[958]: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 4: 1}
```

Comment: The issue is `lambda x: list(x)` but this is due to my data

Comment: Updated now for that case

Comment: Your code reduces my df from 1135 to 37 instead of 1094 (my script renders exactly what I want). For some reason (group_by I think), your code groups a line with 1781 values !
Maybe if you add a row `E` with `[mr E]` you'll see the pb

Answer (score 0):

One solution is

```
df_to_rearrange.drop(df_to_rearrange.index[np.where((df_to_rearrange.index==j))], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

.reindex() as an alternative of .loc

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike

```
df_to_rearrange.reindex([index_to_fetch], ["df_pname"]).append(df_to_rearrange.reindex([j], ["df_pname"]))
```